# Determine network interface of inbound UDP broadcast packet

Tags: java, linux, udp, netty, broadcast

I'm using `netty` 4 to write a `UDP` server. My goal is to receive broadcast packets and send a (broadcast) response. (It's actually `DHCP`, but I don't think that matters for my question.)

As I cannot bind to a single interface and listen for broadcast packets without being root, I bound to any:

```
Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
bootstrap.group(eventLoopGroup)
    .channel(NioDatagramChannel.class)
    .option(ChannelOption.SO_BROADCAST, true)
    .handler(new DhcpChannelInitializer());
bootstrap.bind(67);
```

In my message handler (ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter) I need to send a broadcast packet in response. Problem is, that "255.255.255.255" doesn't work. So I need the interface's broadcast address. But I don't know through which interface the inbound packet came.

**Is there a way to tell through which interface (local address) the packet came?** `((DatagramPacket) msg).recipient()` gives 0.0.0.0 - as it's a broadcast.

If that is not possible my workaround would be to query all interfaces and send the packet to all broadcast addresses. But this creates unnecessary traffic. **Any suggestions?**

Comment: Not in Java. It's possible in C but it requires an option that Java doesn't provide.

Comment: @EJP - Could you tell me what option it is? We can add it to the epoll transport.